# docpad run keeps asking for Terms of Service

Tags: npm, docpad

after updating npm, installing docpad (npm install -g docpad)
i've validate that my PATH has git and npm.
i use docpad run
and i got the following output:

> C:\Work\Edu\docpad>docpad run
>
> > info: Welcome to DocPad v6.69.0 (global installation: C:\Users\Eliran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docpad)
> >     notice: If everyone who saw this message donated $1/week, maintaining DocPad wou
> >     ld become sustainable: http://docpad.org/donate
> >     info: Contribute: http://docpad.org/docs/contribute
> >     info: Plugins:
> >     info: Environment: development
> >     Before we continue, have you read and agree to DocPad's Terms of Service () and Privacy Policy ()? [Y/n] Y

C:\Work\Edu\docpad>

now nothing happens, its just like i've pressed "n".
tried several times, any tips ?
using windows 8.1 64bit.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a known issue and is referenced here:

https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/851

https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/488

The workaround described is to manually create the .docpad.cson file in your Windows/Users/[username]/ directory with the following (sample) content:

```
{
   name: "Your name"
   email: "Your email"
   username: "Your username"
   subscribed: true
   subscribeTryAgain: null
   tos: true
   identified: true
}
```

Once the file is created, start docpad as before.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `docpad run --silent` to skip that question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @syner2 is a good permanent answer. There is also the option to add the `--offline` parameter when you run docpad, as mentioned in [this bug report](https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/854).

Also, this is most definitely a bug. It will hopefully be fixed in the future, or at least a useful error should be displayed to make it easier to lookup the issue.